# How can I manage rubygems version with bundler?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I just started learning Ruby, and for my sandbox I use latest Rubygems version, according to examples and tutorials.

At the same time I have Redmine, which requires Rubygems 1.6.2.

To manage gem versions I use bundler, but can I use it to manage Rubygems version too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think so - I believe it uses your current rubygem from the environment.

However you can use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) to manage the rubygems version, so if you install it and have a [project specific gemset](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/best-practices/) in your .rvmrc file.

I think rvm is OSX/unix only - there is an alternative for Windows I believe.